# Configuring shared cookies in Edge IE mode: wildcards or variable possible?

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, microsoft-edge

To configure shared cookies between Edge and IE [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-add-guidance-cookieshare#overview) states that you have to configure the name attribute of said cookie. However, in our case the cookie name contains the userid of the logged on user: *cookie:userid@website.com*. How would one configure this? I don't see any documentation about wildcards or a variable like %username%.

Answer (score 1):

According to the content of the document, the name attribute of `<shared-cookie>` element `must be exact matches` the cookie's name you need to be shared.
[image]
And the domain attribute and name attribute are required. So I don't think there are any wildcards or the like. For more details, you could refer to the configuration examples and related configuration instructions in the document as appropriate:[Cookie sharing from Microsoft Edge to Internet Explorer-Updated schema elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode-add-guidance-cookieshare#updated-schema-elements).

Comment: Apparently the name attribute is not the name displayed in Windows Explorer. It's the name you see when using F12 developer tools on the website. This way I found the name, which was something like: fAuth.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the name attribute in `Windows Explorer`, can you provide more details? If possible, post sample screenshots so that we can better understand your current problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I assumed the name attribute was the displayname in Explorer, but this is not the case. The name attribute of the cookie can only be viewed when using F12 dev tools when loading the page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Name attribute can be found using F12 website developer tools. Name displayed in Explorer is not the name attribute needed for the sitelist XML